# Inner Exception error time out

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I receive the following 1 of 2  SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

2 of 2 Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out whenever application hits this line of code. all of them are wrapped inside a foreach loop that runs other processes

```
ProcessedRecord = context.ChangeManagement
   .Where(c => c.Person_NUMBER == Testing.Person_NUMBER)
   .GroupBy(c => c.ID)
   .Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(g => g.CREATED).FirstOrDefault())
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I go about fixing this? if u need to see more code I'll let add just let me know

Comment: How long does it take to execute the generated SQL in ssms? If you get also a timeout there, do you have other queries running on this table? Do you have an index on `Person_NUMBER`?

Comment: have you tried killing Entity Framework with fire and never using it again?

Comment: There is no index on CREATED, it  returns very quickly in ssms in under a second.

Comment: @RichBryant no not yet but am getting there

Comment: Try running SQL Profiler (from SSMS Tools menu) against your query to see what's actually going on.  Timeouts can be extended in the connection string but I don't think that;'s your problem here.

Comment: @RichBryant Command timeouts can't be modified in the connection string. Either way, as you suggest, timeout problems shouldn't be "fixed" by extending timeouts. The problem is in the query itself.

Comment: Since you only take the first grouping you may as well remove the grouping altogether. Just order the results by `g.CREATED` (desc.) and take the first one. Currently it's arbitrary which `ID` will be first anyway. Which doesn't mean you shouldn't check the SQL query.

Comment: it returns in 00:00:01 

@GertArnold how do u suggest i improve the query?

Comment: Gert : You are wrong. Large databases the timeout for a query is 15 seconds and many queries can take much longer.  I have queries that take over 30 minutes to complete.  The timeout is a property of the SQL Command.

Comment: I'd use a sproc and a micro-ORM myself.  If you want, you could select everything after the WHERE clause into an IList and do your sorting via linq in the middle tier.  Which is ugly and a waste of the power of SQL Server but then, so is Entity Framework.

Comment: Something like this
processedRecord = context.DC_Bulk_Exit_Daily.Where(c =>c.CUST_NUMBER == exitEntry.CUST_NUMBER).OrderByDescending(g => g.CREATED).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng To clarify: if the timeout is the problem, extending the timeout is not the solution. Of course there are queries requiring longer timeouts, which is OK for unattended processes. But I think OP's first approach should be to improve the query, not to extend the timeout.

Comment: Gert : You are making a big assumption with no proof.  Older versions of SQL Express get fragment easily and slows down queries significantly and the issue has nothing to do with the query itself.

Comment: *it returns in 00:00:01* -- So where does the timeout come from? Could it be related to the foreach loop? What do you mean by "other processes"? Perhaps the database server is too busy at that moment?